# Подкрашивание колонок в datatables по условию при создании таблицы

Tags: javascript, datatable

Есть функция, которая получает два массива:

- дни - `days = [1,2,3..31]` и
- праздники - `holidays = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1...]`

и создает `datatable`

```
function CreateTable(days, holidays) {
  var cols_count = [ {title: "users" } ];
  for (var i = 1; i <= days.length; i++) {
    var elem = { title: i };
    cols_count.push(elem);
  }

  table = $('#calendar_work').DataTable({
    //data: data,
    paging:    false,
    searching: true,
    ordering:  false,
    columns:   cols_count,

    } );
}
```

Как доработать функцию вот с таким условием:

```
for (var j; j<=holidays.length; j++) {
  if ( holidays[j] = 1 ) {
    подкрасим фон этого столбца серым
  }
}
```

Я бекенд программист, но приходится заниматься фронтендом, и пока плохо получается.